# Let $S=\lbrace a+bi \in \mathbb{C} \colon a^2+b^2=1 \rbrace$. Show that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S=\lbrace a+bi \in \mathbb{C} \colon a^2+b^2=1 \rbrace$. Show that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $S$, where $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are additive groups of real numbers and integers respectively. I manage to show that $S$ is a group. But I stuck at defining the map between the two groups. How should I define a map here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try $\phi: \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to S$, where $\phi(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$.

Answer (score 5):

Define the map $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to S$, by $r \mapsto e^{2\pi i r}$.  This map is a surjective homomorphism (verify it).  Now find the kernel and apply the first isomorphism theorem.